# Error processing request from MAD on result: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain

Tags: xcode

**Error processing request from MAD on result: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain**

New after update to Xcode 15:

Error processing request from MAD on result: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-128 "Request was canceled"

Here is my code which I call within my `GameViewController's viewDidLoad().`

```
    func setupMovie(theMovieName: String) {
        
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "movies/" + theMovieName,
                                          ofType:"mp4") else {
            print("movie not found")
            return
        }
        
        itsMoviePlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        itsPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        itsPlayerController?.player = itsMoviePlayer I’m
        itsMovieIsFinished = true

    }   // setupMovie
```

Here is my code which I call at various times via `playMovie(movieName: "pose"):`

```
    func playMovie(movieName: String) {
               
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying),
                                   name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                   object: itsPlayerController?.player?.currentItem)
        
        present(itsPlayerController!, animated:true) {
            self.itsMoviePlayer?.play()
            self.itsMovieIsFinished = false
        }

    }   // playMovie

    
    @objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
        
        self.dismiss(animated:true, completion:nil)
        nextScene()
        changeScene()
        
        // re-init for next time
        setupMovie(theMovieName: "pose")
        
    }
```

#### NB:

1. If I do not call playMovie ==> NO ERROR
2. THE PROBLEM = my call to `present` within `playMovie.`  If I totally comment out `present,` = NO ERROR
3. If I comment out just the guts of `present,` other errors are introduced.
4. I have checked the syntax of calling `present` and I don't see any error there.
5. All the above pertains to the Destination = iPad Mini (6th Generation
6. If the Destination = Apple TV, then we also get within `GameViewDidLoad`
   `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`
7. For both Destinations, the Game runs OK - it's just these Warnings??

!!!!!!!!!!

8. One last statement = if I comment out the call to `NotificationCenter` => Error stays => my call to `present` is the most likely suspect.

!!!!!!!!!!

#### HAALP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again a big Shout Out to DTS with whom I opened up an **offical** TSI.

1. DTS responded that the true culprit is most likely LOG NOISE = Errors or Warnings that do not stop my Code from working. Their effect is superficial, versus substantial.
2. They specifically mentioned several of the posts by Quinn the Eskimo on the Apple Developer Forum which essentially conclude that I ignore this LOG NOISE **as long as** my Code remains 100% functional.
3. DTS also re-credited my TSI Count.

CHEERS!! CHEERS!! CHEERS!!